# How can I reproduce a Reel from Instagram on my website through the embed code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, instagram

I need to embed a reel on my website. I can see the reel but I can not reproduce it. If I embed a video I can see it on my website or a carousel. With the reels I can only see the caption and a button that says `WATCH ON INSTAGRAM`.

I noticed it is with some of the reels, for example I created this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-cxsls2?file=/src/App.tsx where I added 2 different reels, one of them I can play it once and when it ends a button comes up with the label `WATCH AGAIN ON INSTAGRAM`, the other reel always have the same `WATCH ON INSTAGRAM` button/label.

I am using only the embed code, I am wondering if with the oembed library from FB SDK, this will happen as well https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-oembed/

Do you have an idea if they the same behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are going through the same problem. We couldn't solve it completely, but after investigating and testing, we came to the conclusion that there is a copyright issue with the songs that are used in reels.

All reels with the same copyrighted song cannot be viewed, regardless of the user or account. Furthermore, although we were able to test this, there are some videos that have no music and still cannot be played, but at least we were able to confirm that the ones with copyright cannot be played.